# Implementation of counting sort

Tags: c, sorting

I'm trying to learn more about counting sort and I just implemented the example given in CLRS,  my question is: **How can I improve this code**?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void counting_sort(int *, int, int);
int find_max(int *, int);

int main(void)
{
    int l_size;
    int i;

    scanf("%d", &l_size);

    int *num_list = calloc(l_size, sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < l_size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &num_list[i]);


    int max = find_max(num_list, l_size);
    counting_sort(num_list, l_size, max);

    puts("Sorted:");
    for (i = 0; i < l_size; i++)
        printf("%d ", num_list[i]);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}

void counting_sort(int *num_list, int l_size, int max)
{
    int i, j;

    int *count_list = calloc(max + 1, sizeof(int)); // auxiliary array C
    int *sorted_list = calloc(l_size, sizeof(int)); 

    for (i = 0; i < l_size; i++)
        count_list[num_list[i]]++;

    for (i = 1; i < max + 1; i++)
        count_list[i] += count_list[i - 1];


   for (i = l_size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
        sorted_list[count_list[num_list[i]] - 1] = num_list[i];
        count_list[num_list[i]]--;
   }    

   memcpy(num_list, sorted_list, l_size * sizeof(int));
}

int find_max(int *num_list, int l_size)
{
    int i;
    int max = num_list[0];

    for (i = 1; i < l_size; i++)
    {
        if (num_list[i] > max)
            max = num_list[i];
    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: Avoid `sizeot(TYPE)` in favor of `sizeof expr`: Repetition is error-prone.

Comment: Actually you don’t need `sorted_list` at all, since you are just sorting ints (the indices are equal to the data members). Simply write `count_list[i]` times the value `i` in the `num_list` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid modifying the input parameter num_list and the memcopy by returning the sorted list pointer. All relevant changes to your code are marked with // (1) in the code below.

You also have a memory leak in counting_sort since you don't release count_list. The fix is marked // (2).

Same for the lists in main // (3)

**Note** : The program also seg faults when negative data is entered. You either have to guard against that, or also find the minimum data value,  allocate count_list big enough and fix the indices when accessing it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int* counting_sort(int *, int, int); // (1)
int find_max(int *, int);

int main(void)
{
    int l_size;
    int i;

    scanf("%d", &l_size);

    int *num_list = calloc(l_size, sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < l_size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &num_list[i]);


    int max = find_max(num_list, l_size);
    int* sorted = counting_sort(num_list, l_size, max); // (1)

    puts("Sorted:");
    for (i = 0; i < l_size; i++)
        printf("%d ", sorted[i]); // (1)

    printf("\n");

    free(sorted); // (3)
    free(num_list); // (3)

   return 0;
}

int* counting_sort(int *num_list, int l_size, int max) // (1)
{
  int i, j;

  int *count_list = calloc(max + 1, sizeof(int)); // auxiliary array C
  int *sorted_list = calloc(l_size, sizeof(int));

  for (i = 0; i < l_size; i++)
    count_list[num_list[i]]++;

  for (i = 1; i < max + 1; i++)
    count_list[i] += count_list[i - 1];


  for (i = l_size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      sorted_list[count_list[num_list[i]] - 1] = num_list[i];
      count_list[num_list[i]]--;
    }

  free(count_list);  // (2)

  return sorted_list;  // (1)
}

int find_max(int *num_list, int l_size)
{
    int i;
    int max = num_list[0];

    for (i = 1; i < l_size; i++)
    {
        if (num_list[i] > max)
            max = num_list[i];
    }

    return max;
}
```